# La lueur indiquant qui se tient dangereusement trop près d'une crête

Tags: pronoms, pronoms-relatifs

*Les embrouilles de Calma* de Barry Jonsberg :

> Mme Leanyer s'est donc retournée vers nous. J'ai peut-être été la
> première à remarquer l'étincelle de démence dans ses yeux, la lueur
> indiquant **qui** se tient dangereusement trop près d'une crête, et qu'une
> simple poussée suffit à faire basculer.

Je ne comprends pas quel est le rôle de *qui* dans *la lueur indiquant qui se tient dangereusement*. J'écrirais *la lueur qui se tient dangereusement trop près d'une crête* ou *la lueur indiquant qu'elle se tient dangereusement trop près d'une crête*.

Comment: Encore une faute de traduction. Il serait bon d'indiquer l'anglais pour ces questions.

Comment: @Lambie Qu'est-ce qui te permet de juger qu'il s'agit d'une faute de traduction alors que tu ne disposes pas de l'original ?

Comment: Parce qu'une rétrotraduction ne marcherait pas. Aussi le mot crête, Ici on anglais, il s'agit surement de "cliff edge" et pas "ridge". People who are nuts are on the edge of a cliff, not a ridge. [...] the light in them showing she was dangerously close to the cliff's edge and a simple push would send her over. The only other back-translation would be: the light showing **who** was dangerously close to the cliff's edge, and that makes no sense here. Elle était au bord d'une falaise  pas "*près* d'une crête".

Comment: @Lambie Rien n'impose qu'il y ait une falaise. La crête signifie ici pour moi la limite entre deux versants, celui de la normalité et celui de la folie. On peut aussi imaginer que les pentes ne sont pas identiques de part et d'autre de cette crête, d'où l'idée de risque de bascule.

Comment: @jlliagre Oh my god: People are said to be on the edge of a cliff, not on the edge of a ridge. Yes, the ridge is between two slopes. No good writer says he fells off the ridge. The term is to fall off a cliff. To be on the cliff's edge. You can argue all you want, it just is not good. And I'll bet you it is cliff edge in English and not "ridge".

Comment: @Lambie Personne ne parle de **tomber**, le verbe est **basculer**.

Comment: On ne traduit pas toujours mot à mot, sinon les textes traduits seraient très maladroits // Il faudrait rester poli et **bienveillant**, même lorsque l'on n'est pas d'accord avec quelqu'un, c'est la base. _Oh my god_ et _You can argue all you want_ ... // Et puis, l'original anglais importe peu, le texte français est bien suffisant.

Comment: OMG, n'est pas mal polie. OMG=indique la surprise. Oui, on ne traduit pas mot-à-mot, mais il faut comprendre l'anglais aussi. Et ici le traducteur ne l'a pas compris.

Comment: @jlliagre La traduction vers l'anglais de **une simple poussée suffit à faire basculer** veut dire **en anglais**: a simple push would **send her over**. Please stop misreading me all the time.

Comment: C'est un forum français... La question et le texte sont en français. Il faut avant tout être logique et bienveillant, et ne pas donner des ordes _il faut comprendre l'anglais_. // Je ne te répondrai plus, ça sert à rien. :(:(:( Comme toujours.

Comment: @Oreste **le traducteur, le traducteur n'a pas compris l'anglais**, donc, le traducteur a fait des fautes. Je parle dès le début de mauvaise **traduction**. C'est permis quand même et cela explique le français que ce traducteur a utilisé.  Je ne parle pas des participants.

Comment: @Lambie Tu as écrit *fall off a cliff*, j'ai écrit *Personne ne parle de tomber*, tu réponds *send her over, stop misreading me all the time*.

Comment: @jlliagre Yes, **the idiom in English: to fall off a cliff**, not a ridge (crête)  That does not mean the backtranslation requires the word fall...at all.  In fact, if you are close to a ridge, you probably wouldn't fall. If you are close to a ridge, you are probably safe. The English may have even been: close to the edge-close to going crazy.

Comment: @Lambie Il n'y a pas de falaise. Tu t'es construit un original imaginaire et ensuite tu déclares que le traducteur s'est trompé en le traduisant. Tout ça n'a aucun sens.

Comment: @jlliagre To be close to the edge: to be close to going crazy. And **the image for that is a cliff, not a ridge**. Being close to a ridge does not mean close to going crazy. If you  fall off the edge [of the cliff], you have gone crazy. That is the main metaphor here.

Comment: @Lambie Rien de dit qu'il y ait un *ridge* dans l'original anglais. Il ne s'agit peut-être que d'une frontière. Le traducteur aura ajouté l'image de la crête pour accentuer la séparation entre versants.

Comment: @jlliagre une créte is a ridge. There is no other backtranslation for it. Unless you say crest, which is even worse here. She was close to the edge (le bord de la démence) and a simple push would send her over. As in: basculer dans la démence.

Comment: @Lambie *She was close to the edge and a simple push would send her over* Oui, c'est une bonne image de ce que je comprends. Cet *edge* n'a pas besoin d'être une falaise en français. Une expression française similaire : *être sur le fil du rasoir*.

Comment: @jlliagre C'était pour **expliquer** l'image en anglais, C'est tout. Razor's edge is different. Au bord de la démence. En tout cas, maintenant tu vois pour crête ne va absolument pas ici. Au moins bord de la falaise [de la démence] ne rate pas l'image.

Answer (score 3):

*Qui* est un pronom interrogatif attribut dans une proposition interrogative indirecte.

> j'ai été la première à remarquer dans son regard la lueur de démence indiquant **qui** se tient trop près du bord...

> J'ai été la première à remarquer dans son regard cette lueur de démence qui trahit **quelqu'un** proche de basculer du côté obscur...

*Qui* n'a pas d'antécédent mais fait ici indirectement référence à Mme Leanyer. C'est bien elle qui est décrite, elle qui se tient trop près de la crête et qui risque de basculer au-delà.

Cette crête est une métaphore qui représente la frontière entre normalité et démence.

[image]
<sub>Wikipédia: ligne de [crête](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cr%C3%AAte)</sub>

La lueur dans le regard de cette femme trahit sa proximité avec la démence, avec une crise de folie qui ne va pas tarder à se manifester.

Pour information, voici le texte original :

> *Miss Leanyer turned toward the class. I might have been the first to see it—that mad look in her eyes, **like someone who has been really close to an edge and then suddenly gets a shove that puts them right over**. I can’t swear to it, obviously. Maybe even then she would have kept control. Difficult to say. But if you want my opinion, it was Kiffo’s smirk and his comment —“Sorry, Miss, it slipped” — that really did the damage.*

Sa traduction en français n'a pas repris exactement les expressions originales plus proches de : *Comme quelqu'un qui s'est vraiment rapproché d'un seuil/d'une falaise/d'une limite et qui soudain reçoit une poussée qui le fait basculer au-delà.*

Comment: Je comprend plutôt le "qui" ici comme un pronom interrogatif plutôt qu'un pronom relatif se référant à Mme Leanyer: la lueur indique qui va tomber.

Comment: @Greg Tu veux dire que cette lueur indique que Mme Leanyer se demande qui se tient près d'une crête ?

Comment: Non: je comprend la phrase comme "la lueur indique quelle personne se tient trop près de la crête". Si on décompose en plusieurs phrases, on pourrait dire: "qui se tient trop près ?" => c'est la lueur qui indique la réponse à cette question => la lueur indique qui se tient , etc.

Comment: (suite) c'est un construction similaire à ceci, qui est plus clair (j'espère): "le règlement indique qui peut participer". "Qui" est alors un pronom interrogatif introduisant une proposition interrogative indirecte.

Comment: @Greg Dans ce cas, on a la même interprétation grammaticale du *qui*. La seule différence est que pour toi la question est ouverte tandis que pour moi, le contexte implique qu'il s'agit d'elle-même. Ex: *L'autre, beaucoup plus jeune, plus petit et pesant bien quarante kilos de moins, portait un costume qui montrait qui était le patron*.

Comment: @Greg l'a bien formulé, la lueur indique qui (Mme Leanyer dans notre cas) frise la folie. // N'empêche, je trouve la phrase inutilement compliquée.

Comment: Merci beaucoup :) jlliagre

Comment: @Oreste: j'avoue avoir du la relire 3 ou 4 fois... je la trouve aussi assez alambiquée...

Answer (score 1):

*Qui* est un sujet dans la relative indéfinie « qui se tient dangereusement trop près d'une crête. »

Comme on pourrait le trouver dans la phrase « Qui dort dîne. » Ici *qui* n'indique pas une personne en particulier, ou ne reprend pas un sujet, mais fait office de sujet non déterminé.